# AIX C call python Error

Tags: python-2.7, aix, python-embedding

I made a simple testcase:

```
#include "Python.h" 

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    Py_Initialize(); 
    if ( !Py_IsInitialized() ) 
    { 
        return -1; 
    } 

    PyRun_SimpleString("import io");

    Py_Finalize(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

and then I ran it:

```
# gcc testpy.c -o hello2 -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7  -lnsl -ldl  -lpthread -lm
# ./hello2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io ImportError:
    0509-130 Symbol resolution failed for /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so because:
    0509-136   Symbol PyUnicodeUCS2_Replace (number 1) is not exported from dependent module hello2.
    0509-136   Symbol PyList_New (number 2) is not exported from dependent module hello2.
    0509-136   Symbol PyString_FromStringAndSize (number 3) is not exported from dependent module hello2.
    0509-136   Symbol _Py_ZeroStruct (number 5) is not exported from dependent module hello2.
    0509-136   Symbol PyModule_AddIntConstant (number 6) is not exported from dependent module hello2.
    0509-136   Symbol PyUnicodeUCS2_FromStringAndSize (number 7) is not exported from dependent module hello2.
    0509-021 Additional errors occurred but are not reported.
    0509-192 Examine .loader section symbols with the 'dump -Tv' command.

# uname
AIX7.1 p720
```

Can someone give some advice on this?

Comment: What is the output of `ldd ./hello2`?  Within python, what is the output of `sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBS')` and `sysconfig.get_config_var('LINKFORSHARED')`?  (See https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems)